# how to remove the chevrondown button in treegrid???? in Lightning Web Component - Tree Grid

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, slds-grid, lightningtreegrid

I checked here https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/#site-main-content that there is an option to "When a branch doesn't have children, apply slds-is-disabled to the corresponding slds-button_icon element." but where should I add this "slds-is-disabled"???

I tried to add here, but its not working

```
<lightning-tree-grid class="slds-is-disabled"
            columns={gridColumns}
            data={gridData}
            key-field="xxx"
            onrowselection={handleSelection}
            ontoggle={handleRowToggle}>
</lightning-tree-grid>
```

should I have to add something in my JS code?

Comment: Could you please share your code and explain where you have tried to add it?

Comment: sure<lightning-tree-grid class="slds-is-disabled"
            columns={gridColumns}
            data={gridData}
            key-field="xxx"
            onrowselection={handleSelection}
            ontoggle={handleRowToggle}>
</lightning-tree-grid>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the behaviour implemented in lightning-tree-grid. You don't have to add anything else. If you take a look at the basic example in the documentation you'll see that the first row doesn't have the chevron, because it has no children:

[image]

The instructions for creating a tree grid with SLDS would apply if you weren't using the lightning-tree-grid base component for any reason. Makes sense?

Comment: yes! i found out that the problem is in the way im getting the data. thanks!